# Google Apps: Array.map() - how to throw error to one index only

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, error-handling, array-formulas

I have a custom function in Google Sheets. I pass as parameters a string, a range and a number N (an index) and it looks up the string on the range, then it returns me the value of cell N positions away from my found item. So in the table below:

```
  A B C D
1 z y w v
2 q w e r
3 i d e a
4 s t a r
```

if I run `=myfunc('q',A:D,2)` it returns me `'e'`. Not too different from a `vlookup()` but mine searches everywhere in the table (not just the first column) and can return values to the left of the found value, like `=myfunc('v', A:D, -2)` returns `'y'`.

Now I'm coding error handling so if the index to return is out of range, it throws an error with this code `throw new Error( "Item out of range." );`. As I don't return this, Google Sheet identifies as a spreadsheet error, like I want.

My problem is this: when I use myfunc inside an ArrayFormula() it works fine, unless there is one value out of range, then Google apps throws an error to all the rows in the column. I made a simpler prototype below:

```
function testError(range) {
  var cellRef;
  if (range.map) {
    return range.map(function (x) {
      cellRef = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange(x).getValue();

      //(*) below is the problem!!!
      if (cellRef == 'q') throw new Error("Error on purpose on cell A2");
      return cellRef;
    });
  }
  else {
    cellRef = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange(range).getValue();

    // (**) below works fine!!
    if (cellRef == 'q') throw new Error("Error on purpose on cell A2");
    return cellRef;
  }
}
```

So, in my sheets when I type it like this `=testerror(address(row(A:A),column(A:A)))` in all the rows (from any column, because I'm referring to `column(A:A)` here, the second row (referring to cell A2) shows an Error, like intended (**). But if I type this `=ArrayFormula(testerror(address(row(A:A),column(A:A))))` in the first row of any column, nothing will show up as there will be a single error to all the column (*).

To ilustrate, cell E1, E2, E3 and E4 have the following formula: `=testerror(address(row(),column(A:A)))` and F1 has the following `=ArrayFormula(testerror(address(row(A:A),column(A:A))))`. Below is the result:

```
  A B C D E      F
1 z y w v z      #ERROR
2 q w e r #ERROR
3 i d e a i
4 s t a r s
```

As you see, the results of column F didn't populate, because it threw one error. For my array part, if I substitute that line (*) for something like this:
`if (cellRef == 'q') return "String for ERROR on A2";` the result is:

```
  A B C D E      F
1 z y w v z      z
2 q w e r #ERROR "String for ERROR on A2"
3 i d e a i      i
4 s t a r s      s
```

Now it doesn't break my `map()` but that's because I returned a string. So, how do I throw an error to that cell only when using `ArrayFormula()`?

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping `if (cellRef == 'q') throw new Error("Error on purpose on cell A2");` inside a try catch and handling the throws/return values that way? It's difficult to properly understand what you need with your examples alone, could you sanitise and share a copy of your sheet?